# Can't put the panel at the specified position on wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I can get the correct result if I don't comment the `self.panel1`. If I comment the `self.panel1`. The panel2 can't render at position(200,0). It take the full frame window.

Following is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
   def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(400,400))    

        # self.panel1=wx.Panel(parent=self,
        #                      size=(200,200),
        #                      pos=(0,0),
        #                      style=wx.BORDER)            

        self.panel2=wx.Panel(parent=self,
                             size=(200,200),
                             pos=(200,0),
                             style=wx.BORDER)


# Run the program
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyForm().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wxWidget - `wxFrame` documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_frame.html):

> `wxFrame` processes the following events:
>
> `wxEVT_SIZE`: **if the frame has exactly one child window, not counting
>   the status and toolbar, this child is resized to take the entire frame
>   client area**. If two or more windows are present, they should be laid
>   out explicitly either by manually handling wxEVT_SIZE or using sizers;

Workaround: Make a extra panel (`outer_panel` in the following example) to contain a single panel.

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
   def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(400,400))    
        self.outer_panel = wx.Panel(self) # <--------------
        self.panel2=wx.Panel(parent=self.outer_panel,
                             size=(200,200),
                             pos=(200,0),
                             style=wx.BORDER)
        self.panel2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)

app = wx.App(False)
MyForm().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

**UPDATE**
Another solution suggested by Robin Dunn; catch frame's EVT_SIZE to prevent the default handler from being called.

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
   def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(400,400))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, lambda *args: 0) # <--------
        self.panel2=wx.Panel(parent=self,
                             size=(200,200),
                             pos=(200,0),
                             style=wx.BORDER)


app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyForm().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Or, as the docs suggest, you can catch the frame's EVT_SIZE in order to prevent the default handler from being called.

Comment: @RobinDunn, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer according to you. :)